# Rails form_for keeps trying to use PUT, when my route is a POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my routes file:

```
resources :payments do
  member do
    post :add_payment
  end
end
```

With rake routes looking like this:

```
add_payment_payment POST   /payments/:id/add_payment(.:format)     payments#add_payment
```

And my form_for tag has this:

```
<%= form_for @loan, :url => add_payment_payment_path, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

Yet when i submit the form, I keep getting this error:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/payments/4/add_payment"
```

Why does it keep trying to use PUT instead of POST?

Comment: Could it be that your `@loan` has been persisted before, therefore form_for tries to create a PUT form? Need to see controller code

Comment: You can see in these examples http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html if the object exists then `form_for` will add `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />` to the HTML.